# Compilng s_sin.c of GNU libm after changing the source

Tags: c, glibc, libm

I want to slightly modify libm's `sin` function (source: [s_sin.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c;hb=HEAD#l281)) to experiment with something numerical. However,  I don't see how to compile the modified source.

I would like to avoid doing "./configure, make". So, to resolve all dependencies,  I tried to compile s_sin.c with libm.a in my system. But my compiler quickly rejects the compilation as it cannot find the header file "mydefs.h" in the source file. There are many such header files in the source.

My question is: what is the easiest way for experimenting with changing a single math function in GNU libm and the compiling it? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `./configure; make`? That should go into the question (because it is the normal build procedure). You might be interested by some `--prefix`  passed to `configure`, and/or by [chroot(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html) facilities such as [schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot). Otherwise, your question is some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). In all cases, you should **edit your question** to motivate it and give a lot more information (and context)

Comment: You could also play with [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) since it is designed to co-exist with `glibc`

Comment: Also, you could `./configure; make` without the next `make install` and play with the `libc` in your build tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to avoid doing "./configure, make".

You cannot avoid that (since it is the usual build procedure), but you could pass more arguments to `configure`. Try `configure --help` first. You could avoid the next `make install` (or pass some `DESTDIR=/tmp/somedir/` to it).

> My question is: what is the easiest way for experimenting with changing a single math function in GNU libm and the compiling it?

I would recommend a small [chroot(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html)-ed environment. Debian has [schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) and [debootstrap](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/debootstrap) to make that reasonably easy.

Then you still do `./configure` -perhaps with a different `--prefix` ...- followed by `make`. You may or not want `make install`

Consider perhaps playing with [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/), since it can coexist with your system's `libc`

BTW, `sin` is an unusual function (like many in `-lm`). You could set a breakpoint there to check that most of your system programs don't use it. Don't forget to backup the system's `libc`  and have some *static* shell running just in case (perhaps `sash`, because many core utilities are builtin: a static `sash` contains *internal* variants of `tar`, `cp`, `mv` etc... that don't depend on any external `libc`)

Your could also add (temporarily) some `#define sin(x) mysin(x)` in some header (e.g. `/usr/include/math.h`) or use [`LD_PRELOAD` tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/426230/841108).

(it is unclear what you *really* want to do. `libm.so` is only used by programs, not by itself; what actual numerical experiments do you want to do ??).